# Task.WhenAll with LINQ select

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

```
long[] orderIds={10,11,12,13};

var orders= new List<Order>();

await Task.WhenAll(orderIds.Select(async (orderId) =>
{
    var orderDetails = await GetOrderDetails(orderId);

    if (orderDetails != null)
        orders.Add(orderDetails);
}));
```

I am getting some wrong behavior with this, after deployement this code to server its working fine but on local sometimes it is adding all orders but sometime it missed some orders.

Can anybody please help to short out this, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Its not thread safe, either use a [Concurrent Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8), or return OrderDetails to add afterwards (which would simplify what you are doing somewhat)

Comment: `orders.AddRange( ( await Task.WhenAll( orderIds.Select( id => GetOrderDetails(id) ) ) ).Where( o => o != null ) );`

Comment: You can use ConcurentBag<T> instead of List<T> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I recommend forcing enumeration of the tasks (e.g. an extra `ToList()` call) before sending them anywhere. You wouldn't want to accidentally enumerate the list more than once.

```
var tasks = orderIds.Select( orderId => GetOrderDetails(orderId) ).ToList();
```

Then await the tasks:

```
await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
```

And voila, your orders are ready.

```
var orders = tasks.Select( t => t.Result ).Where( o => o != null ).ToList();
```

BTW nothing is being mutated so you're completely thread-safe without any need for locks (assuming `GetOrderDetails` is thread-safe). This is one of the [advantages of a functional approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909282/why-are-functional-languages-considered-a-boon-for-multi-threaded-environments) to using linq and in general.

Comment: I love your implementation, but it could be even more simplified like this:
var orders = await Task.WhenAll(orderIds.Select(orderId => GetOrderDetails(orderId)))
   .ContinueWith(all => all.Result.Where(o => o != null).ToList());

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan (1) You missed the point of my first sentence (2) That doesn't compile

Comment: 1) I can't see any point in your first sentence. "Enumerate the list more than once" I don't suppose there's a difference for the WhenAll method, or you can restart the tasks after the consumption. So no, I can't see any point there. 2) There's a typo ordersId => instead of orderId => , and it perfectly compiles with no intermediate variables and extra work.

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan is ContinueWith not wait to complete each task in whenall separately so it seem for each individual task will be synchronous but tasks under whenall will be asynchronous, am I right? also I just read about 1 article on not using ContinueWith, what you will say about that? https://medium.com/@joni2nja/why-you-should-not-use-continuewith-in-your-async-code-c9eaf6087e64

Comment: @JohnWu - could you elaborate on "You wouldn't want to accidentally enumerate the list more than once." - why would that happen in this case? and how does calling toList prevent it. I am a C# newbie I am afraid.

Comment: Note the existence of [`WhenAll<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-1.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task((-0)))))) which would allow you to just `TResult[] result = await Task.WhenAll...etc`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
long[] orderIds = { 10, 11, 12, 13 };

IList<Order> orders = await
    orderIds
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(id => Observable.FromAsync(() => GetOrderDetails(id)))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think it's Microsoft's. And Reactive X is available for a great variety of languages, not only C#.

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan - It is Microsoft's. They created Rx. The popularity of the library is what created all of the ports to the other languages. https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Getting-Started-with-Rx-Extensions-for-NET?term=Rx&pubDate=range&lang-en=true&date-range-from=2001-01-01&date-range-to=2010-12-31

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I didn't know that.

Answer (score -3):

### I assume lock will do.

```
long[] orderIds={10,11,12,13};

var orders= new List<Order>();

await Task.WhenAll(orderIds.Select(async (orderId) =>
{
    var orderDetails = await GetOrderDetails(orderId);

    if (orderDetails != null)
        lock(orders) orders.Add(orderDetails);
}));
```

Comment: Locking on the list itself is usually not a good idea. You probably should have a private (or in this case a local) variable created especially for the purpose of locking.

Comment: @Enigmativity Can explain why? I don't think you're right about it. At least Microsoft's documentations don't mention anything about it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I suppose lock works by creating an entry in a special table which contains the address of the reference type object we provide. Until it's not garbage collected or messed up with reflection, it's fine to use whatever reference object you want.

Comment: Regarding locking on a `List`, you may find interesting the comments of this question: [Is it safe to use a boxed value type as a locker for the lock statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864042/is-it-safe-to-use-a-boxed-value-type-as-a-locker-for-the-lock-statement). TL:DR it is possible in theory that an instance of a `List` could do `lock(this)`. By using a dedicated private locker `object` you can be sure that your locker will not be used concurrently by anybody else.

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan - If you use a variable that other parts of your code have access to then those parts could lock on the same variable and thus your code can't run. It's a terrible bug to diagnose. It's just always best to use a variable that is as private as possible for your code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I highly doubt it, because Microsoft itself suggests "In particular, avoid using the following as lock objects: • this, as it might be used by the callers as a lock." Never use 'this' as a lock object. You're wrong too!

Comment: @Enigmativity I couldn't agree with you more if I were using something that is visible outside of my assembly, maybe public property of my class, and not just a local variable as it is, most likely, in this case.