# Cleanest async version of this foreach?

Tags: c#, .net-core, foreach, async-await

I have a method in an AWS Lambda which receives a completed list of items. It processes those items and then inserts them into a Dynamo DB table. Order of processing or inserting into the DB does not matter.

I'm looking for the most thread-safe, yet easy to understand manner in which to make this run faster; Either by using `async await` or something other (likely parallel?) operations.

I was thinking `Parallel.ForEach()` but that seems a bit heavy. Is there a simpler, more obvious way?

```
private async Task<int> LoadAutocomplete(IList<Item> resp)
{
    var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

    foreach (var item in resp)
    {
        var request = new PutItemRequest
        {
            TableName = EnvironmentHelper.DynamoTableName,
            Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
            {
                { "LANGUAGE", new AttributeValue { S = item.LANGUAGE }},
                { "COUNTRY", new AttributeValue { S = item.COUNTRY }}
            }
        };
        await client.PutItemAsync(request);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

**Option 1**

```
private async Task<int> LoadAutocomplete(IList<Item> resp)
{
    var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

    Parallel.ForEach(resp, async item =>
    {
        var request = new PutItemRequest
        {
            TableName = EnvironmentHelper.DynamoTableName,
            Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
            {
                { "LANGUAGE", new AttributeValue { S = item.LANGUAGE }},
                { "COUNTRY", new AttributeValue { S = item.COUNTRY }}
            }
        };
        await client.PutItemAsync(request);
    }
}
```

*Option 2 causes the compiler to complain that the LoadAutoComplete method "lacks await operators and will run synchronously".*

**Option 2** As suggested by @jamesfaix

```
private async Task<int> LoadAutocomplete(IList<Item> resp)
{
    var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    
    var tasks = items.Select(x => DoSomethingAsync(client, x)).ToList();
    
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private DoSomething(AmazonDynamoDBClient client, Item item)
{
    var request = new PutItemRequest
    {
        TableName = EnvironmentHelper.DynamoTableName,
        Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
        {
            { "LANGUAGE", new AttributeValue { S = item.LANGUAGE }},
            { "COUNTRY", new AttributeValue { S = item.COUNTRY }}
        }
    };
    
    await client.PutItemAsync(request);
}
```

**Options +** *Suggested by @martin*

The post ["Use Parallel.For in batches in dotnet core"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656840/use-parallel-for-in-batches-in-dotnet-core) does respond to my question, but I've chosen [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67928010/71376) posted by @jamesfaix because it has improved my code so much.

Comment: Don't use `Sleep` in async code. Use `await Task.Delay`

Comment: Ah, yes. I've actually removed that line but forgot to here. I might be scuppered by it anyway, because I seem to remember needing that line to ensure the DB inserts perform properly.

Comment: Another thing you can do is start all tasks before awaiting any of them. The runtime will try to optimize their execution based on available threads. For example

```
var tasks = items.Select(x => DoSomethingAsync(x)).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Is it required to impose any concurrency or rate limitations to the whole operation? A concurrency limit denotes how many operations can be concurrently *in-flight* (the duration of the operations matters). A rate limit denotes how many operations can be *started* during any sliding time window (the duration of the operations is irrelevant).

Comment: Please define "clean" in objective terms. Otherwise, this is an exercise in listing all of the ways to do something.

Comment: Between your Option 1 and Option 2, I would be more concerned with behavior difference than syntactic cleanness.

Comment: @heretic-monkey I have refined that requirement in the post. You're right, "clean" is not a good term (but I was hoping that it would be broadly understood.)

Comment: You can reject the "Option 1" without further ado. The `Parallel.ForEach` [is not async friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915707/unexpected-different-results-using-task-whenall-and-parallel-foreach-with-an-ent/67923412#67923412).

Comment: @jamesfaix What do you mean by behaviour difference? AFAIK they would produce the same result, unless I'm missing something about the end product?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, the compiler does not like it, either.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There is no requirement to impost concurrency or rate limitations. Am I implying that there is? If so, I have missed that.

Comment: You mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927835/cleanest-async-version-of-this-foreach#comment120063870_67927835) that "the DB inserts perform properly", by adding a 100 msec delay between operations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There may be due to performance of the client library. I will try it without. 700 records should be enough to test the concern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Parallel.For in batches in dotnet core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656840/use-parallel-for-in-batches-in-dotnet-core) before I copy my answer to this question it maybe helps you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some basic changes I would make to start off with. There may be other improvements you can make from there.

1. Avoid `Thread.Sleep` in async code. `Task.Delay` is the async equivalent.
2. Create many tasks before awaiting any. The runtime will try to run some concurrently if it can.

```
private async Task<int> LoadAutocomplete2(IList<Item> resp)
{
    var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

    var tasks = resp.Select(async item =>
    {
        var request = new PutItemRequest
        {
            TableName = EnvironmentHelper.DynamoTableName,
            Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
            {
                { "LANGUAGE", new AttributeValue { S = item.LANGUAGE }},
                { "COUNTRY", new AttributeValue { S = item.COUNTRY }}
            }
        };

        var result = await client.PutItemAsync(request);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return result;
    })
    .ToList(); // Make sure to materialize the IEnumerable!

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jamesfaix - this has improved the execution time from 1:20 to 0:03 :)

Comment: Why is it important to materialise the `tasks` IEnumerable?

Comment: Is it because of the potential to accidentally enumerate the list multiple times during the `WhenAll` check would cause re-processing of items in the list? (This explanation is my derivation from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60447378/71376)

Comment: That was my thinking. Reading this again, it may be okay without `ToList` because `WhenAll` is the only thing iterating the collection, but I would be cautious if there are any other uses of the collection. It would be easy for a multiple iteration bug to sneak in.